# How to open specific folder in the storage using intent in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have tried so many answers related to this question but didn't work any of them. this my code but it didn't open the myFile folder. Please help me to resolve this issue

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
      val uri = Uri.parse(
            (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath) + "/myFile/")
      intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")
      startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_ACCESS_CODE)
```

[image: This is the result of this code. Only open the recent page]

Comment: `tried so many answers related with this question ` Which question?

Comment: the problem i mentioned. "How to open specific folder in the storage using intent in android"

Comment: You should put all problems and questions in your post. Not in comments or subjects or titles. Write a decent post.

Comment: @blackapps why you answer questions with questions, if you cant help you shoildnt say noyhing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code may help you:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_RESULT_CODE);
```

If you want to open a specific folder:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
 +  File.separator + "myFolder" + File.separator), "file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_RESULT_CODE);
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, thank you so much. Another one question. I can't open the files inside that folder. Is that permission issue?

Comment: Maybe yes, make sure the app has the permissions and the manifest file is correct

Comment: @Sanush Maybe you can try to change "file/*" to something like "image/png". We've tried this can open image files.

Comment: We've tried this solution but still cannot open a specific folder. Are there any other factors to be aware of?

Answer (score 3):

try this -->

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
     +  File.separator + "myFolder" + File.separator);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

OR

```
// location = "/sdcard/my_folder";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri mydir = Uri.parse("file://"+location);
intent.setDataAndType(mydir,"application/*");    // or use */*
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: my both methods failed?

Comment: Don't use this it will result in a android.os.FileUriExposedException

Comment: @basit9 so what have you done for `android.os.FileUriExposedException` ?

Comment: well this was happening because of "file://" so I removed it and in my case the path was starting from "content// :". Complete solution, dir is the path
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(dir), "*/*");

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after API 29:

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        {
            StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();
            //String startDir = "Android";
            //String startDir = "Download"; // Not choosable on an Android 11 device
            //String startDir = "DCIM";
            //String startDir = "DCIM/Camera";  // replace "/", "%2F"
            //String startDir = "DCIM%2FCamera";
            String startDir = "Documents";

            Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI");

            String scheme = uri.toString();

            Log.d(TAG, "INITIAL_URI scheme: " + scheme);

            scheme = scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/");

            scheme += "%3A" + startDir;

            uri = Uri.parse(scheme);

            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri);

            Log.d(TAG, "uri: " + uri.toString());

            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Kotlin**, please see this way:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
intent.setDataAndType(data?.toUri(), "application/vnd.ms-excel") // or application/*
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"))
```

Where **data** is the *location* of your file.