# How to make a shortcut in flutter app to folder in internal storage?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-internal-storage

i'm making a Flutter App that saves some files the folder Android/data/com.example.../files/, and i want to put a icon in the Appbar with a shortcut to that folder so the user could easily have acess to these files using the native file explorer of the  android,Does anybody know how i can do this? any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Android intents for this:
https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus

Here's another SO post about opening a specific folder in Android using an intent, you can replicate that intent with this package (or another similar one)
[How to open specific folder in the storage using intent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62788954/how-to-open-specific-folder-in-the-storage-using-intent-in-android)